# What makes Deep RL "fundamentally/mathematically" advantageous?

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

Note: I consider myself to be a beginner in the field of Deep RL.

Deep RL has proven tremendous success in recent years like playing atari and beating go champion. Therefore, considerable interest for the use of Deep RL was observed. However, I just do not want to go with this wave naively. I prefer to understand what makes Deep RL "fundamentally" advantageous, on a factual/mathematical/algorithmic level, in terms of the computational performance, optimization, generalization, convergence, etc. Surprisingly when I searched, I could not find any satisfying arguments for this.

If there are any published papers in this respect, it would be much appreciated as the argument would be peer-reviewed.

Comment: It's probably for about the same reason as why humans are good at those games. They learn to recognise patterns. On a basic level, this is simply a result of the mathematics involved. On a deeper level, our understanding the patterns any given model is seeing, how all the mathematics combines to find those patterns and why it's effective at finding them is, as far as I know, still quite lacking.

Comment: That is exactly what I have observed so far: "how all the mathematics combines to find those patterns and why it's effective at finding them is, as far as I know, still quite lacking". Deep RL is not like Deep Learning in this regard, I can clearly see why deep learning has achieved what it has achieved. However, for Deep RL the theoretical intuition of this success is "as far as my research" still lacking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will answer your question "mathematically", but it will definitely give you some idea to why it is "advantageous".

---

Usual RL requires to keep in memory a state-value vector. When the number of possible states is large, or even infinite - this is not practical to keep in memory. In addition, the usual RL requirements for convergence require to visit at least a certain number of times each unique state, and having such a large number of states would mean we won't visit most of them, most of the time (and hence you won't really converge. Unless you wait a few thousand years I guess...)

Deep RL tackles this problem by introducing a continuous function that is supposed to predict the "value" of a state given some representation of the state. This means we don't have to store a huge array mapping states to their values, and as such it means its far more practical.

Its also capable of "generalizing" the value of a certain state to other similar states, instead of computing it independently for them.

---

I hope this gave you some intuition on why Deep RL is so popular and powerful :)